# Counting by property state using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Suppose we wish to create an observable that emits a count.  For example we may have a `let todos:Observable<todo[]>` and we wish to know how many of those instances have the `completed` property set to true.  So:

```
 let count = todos.pipe() //do the count
```

Comment: You can use the `.scan` or `.reduce` operators.

Comment: `todos.pipe(map(ts => ts.reduce((total, t) => total + (t.completed ? 1 : 0), 0)))`

Comment: @cartant add that as the answer

Comment: Yes great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `todos` observable emits values that are arrays of todos, so you can use the `map` operator to map the array to the number of completed todos that it contains.

To count the number of completed todos, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` within the `map` operator:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
// ...
const completed = todos.pipe(
  map(ts => ts.reduce(
    (total, t) => total + (t.completed ? 1 : 0),
    0
  ))
);
```